# Sending CSV attachment with action mailer & AWS Sqs queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, amazon-web-services, actionmailer, amazon-sqs

I am trying to send an email with a CSV attachment from a Rails AWS EB application (worker tier).

This example will send the email correctly with the data attached, I have hardcoded the CSV string here;

```
def send_mail
    content = "Example,CSV,Content\n,..."
    attachments['test.csv'] = { mine_type: 'text/csv', content: content}
    mail(   :from => 'test@mail.com>', 
            :to => 'person@mail.com', 
            :subject => 'Email with attachment', 
            :body => "testing sending email attachment"
        )
end
```

However when I send the CSV string from the API I seem to have an encoding problem. The object I am sending is this;

```
email = {
    from: "test@mail.com",
    to: "person@mail.com",
    subject: "Email with attachment",
    content_type: 'text/html',
    attachments: {
        filename: 'test.csv',
        content: File.read("#{Rails.root}/test.csv")
    }
}
```

And the method;

```
def send_mail(params)
    filename = params[:attachments][:filename]
    attachments[filename] = {   mine_type: 'text/csv', 
                                content_type: 'text/comma-separated-values', 
                                transfer_encoding: '7bit',
                                content: [:attachments][:content]
                            }
    mail(params)
end
```

I think there may be a problem with the **transfer_encoding**, If I do not set it to '7bit' the content is base64 encrypted. I have used the action mailer method **attachments.instance_values** to check the content_encoding of the email that works and its binary, however it I set it as binary in the failing example it reverts to base64. If I set the params[:attachments][:content] as a variable then when I log the attachments.instance_values the value is 'binary' but when the mail is received the message is;

```
 ----==_mimepart_57ac6ae25a220_68972ad836f669fc984a7 
    Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values; charset=UTF-8 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
    Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=test.csv 
    mine-type: text/csv 
    Content-ID: <57ac6ae259b90_68972ad836f669fc983b0>
```

any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be mime-type, not mine-type in order to parse correctly.